# Regex of Binary sequence that does not contains 00

Tags: java, c#, regex, binary

I am trying to get a regular expression that:
 - Has any sequence of 0 and 1. (Binary only)
 - And Does not contains 00

I know them separate but how I can combine them?

```
(?:[0-1]+)+
```

the above for sequence of 0101 of any kind.

Here is screenshot of the part of the question:

[image: Here is the part of the question]

any clue reference would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular expressions such as `0?(1+0)*` will match against any part of the string so it will match the middle part of a string such as `000011000000`, it will match the `0110`. To check that the whole string matches need to add the start and end of string anchors, giving `^0?(1+0)*$`. This will also match an empty string. To match against a non-empty string we could use `^0?(1+0)+$` but this will not match a string with a single `0`. So we need to add an alternative (using `|`) to match the `0`, leading to the total expression `^((0?(1+0?)+)|0)$`.

These brackets are capturing brackets, they could be changed to non-capturing forms but that would make the expression bigger and, visually, more complex.

Answer (score 1):

I came to this form:

`0?(1+0?)*`

Explained:

1. `0?` - can start with `0`
2. `1+` - non-empty sequence of `1`s
3. `0?` - followed by at most one `0`
4. `(1+0?)*` - 2-3 repeated any number of times

Comment: Adam, the code matches simple `00` . Demo: https://regex101.com/r/2CFroT/5

Comment: Those are 3 separate matches: first `0`, second `0` (and an empty string).

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
(10)+|(01)+|1+
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/2CFroT/4

Comment: But it also matches `1001` which has `00`... And it won't match `1` nor `0`.

Comment: The thing is the string must NOT match if it contains any sequence of 00. the above match partially. I will update the question above.